# `useQueryClient()` from `react-query` not working in the separated `mutationFn` causing function inexecution

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-typescript, json-server, tanstackreact-query

I'm trying to separate the `mutationFn` from the `useMutation()` so that the code would be a bit easier to read.

However, it turns out that the `useQueryClient()` doesn't seem to work outside the `useDeleteAllTasks()` hook function. I'd like to know why that is the case, and how I could possibly separate the function and still get it to work as I first intended it to.

The backend being used is the JSON Server. Fetching with React Query V5 & Axios.

So here is the code in the `useDeleteAllTasks()` hook, which works perfectly as intended:

```
export const useDeleteAllTasks = () => {
    const currentQuery = useQueryClient()

    return useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['delete-all-tasks'],
        mutationFn: () => {
           const prevTasks = currentQuery.getQueryData<Task[]>(['tasks'])
           const taskArray = prevTasks?.map(task => task.id);
           taskArray?.forEach(id => deleteTaskByID(id))
        },
        onSettled: () => currentQuery.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['tasks'] })
    })
}
```

But I thought this would also work, but doesn't:

```
export const useDeleteAllTasks = () => {
    const currentQuery = useQueryClient()

    return useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['delete-all-tasks'],
        mutationFn: deleteAllTasks
        },
        onSettled: () => currentQuery.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['tasks'] })
    })
}


const deleteAllTasks = () => {
    
    // This logs as expected
    console.log('deleteAllTasks() - 1')

    // This line does NOT seem work, which causes the rest of the function to stop working.
    const currentQuery = useQueryClient()

    // This doesn't show up at all
    console.log('deleteAllTasks() - 2')

    // No response from the function beyond this line
    const prevTasks = currentQuery.getQueryData<Task[]>(['tasks'])
    const taskArray = prevTasks?.map(task => task.id);
    taskArray?.forEach(id => deleteTaskByID(id))

    console.log('deleteAllTasks() - DONE')
}
```

All productive suggestions are welcome :)